# How to use manipulate() on ggplot geom_smooth()

Tags: r, ggplot2

Does anyone know how to use **manipulate()** on a **ggplot**, in order to easily select a smoothing (span) level?  I´ve tried the following without success:

```
# fake data
    xvals <- 1:10
    yvals <- xvals^2*exp(rnorm(2,5,0.6))
    data <- data.frame(xvals,yvals)

# plot with manipulate
    manipulate(
    ggplot(data,aes(xvals,yvals)) +
      geom_smooth(span=slider(0.5,5)) +
      geom_point()
    )
```

I want to be able to cycle through "smoothing levels" easily.

Comment: Inspired by this [example](http://www.r-bloggers.com/a-first-go-at-%E2%80%98manipulate%E2%80%99-in-rstudio/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Changed your data to have more data points.

```
xvals <- 1:100
yvals <- rnorm(100)
data <- data.frame(xvals,yvals)
```

You have to give name for the value used with `span=` in `geom_smooth()` (for example, `span.val`) and then define `span.val=slider(0.1,1)` outside the `ggplot()` function - in this example as second argument to `manipulate()`.

```
library(manipulate)
library(ggplot2)
manipulate({
  #define plotting function 
  ggplot(data,aes(xvals,yvals)) +
    geom_smooth(method="loess",span=span.val) +
    geom_point()},
  #define variable that will be changed in plot
    span.val=slider(0.1,1)
)
```

Comment: What´s the rationale behind having to define the slider value outside the ggplot() call? 
I mean, the very [manipulate() help page](http://www.rstudio.com/ide/docs/advanced/manipulate) suggests its use inside the plot call, I think. See:

  `plot(cars, xlim=c(x.min,x.max)),`
  `x.min=slider(0,15),` 
  `x.max=slider(15,30))`

Comment: In you example in comment you can see that function plot() ends before comma, and then x.min=slider(0,15) is passed as second argument to function manipulate(), not the argument to plot().

Comment: I see now, Didzis. It´s a manipulate() argument not a plot() argument. Thanks :)